# How to add span only on Arabic sentence?

Tags: php, html, css, arabic

In this code I have detected arabic writing. However, how if any Arabic writing and will be added `span` code

```
<?php

/*
 function highlight($text, $words) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
    if(!$m)
        return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}
*/

$arabic = "|ٮ|ٯ|ا|ب|ت|ث|ج|ح|خ|د|ذ|ر|ز|س|ش|ص|ض|ط|ظ|ع|غ|ف|ق|ك|ل|م|ن|ه|و|ي|ء|آ|ٱ|أ|إ|ة|ؤ|ئ|ى|ـ|،|؛|؟|٪|٫|٬|٩|٨|٧|٦|٥|٤|٣|٢|١|٠|ٍ|ِ|ْ|ّ|ٌ|ُ|ً|َ";

$kata = "
Excellence is to worship Allah as if you see Him
أَنْ تَعْبُدَ اللَّهَ كَأَنَّكَ تَرَاهُ فَإِنْ
 for you do not see Him but He certainly sees you.
";

if(mb_ereg(".*[$arabic].*", $kata)) {
    echo $kata;
}
else
{
    echo "Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.";
}

?>
```

To be like this

```
Excellence is to worship Allah as if you see Him 
<span> أَنْ تَعْبُدَ اللَّهَ كَأَنَّكَ تَرَاهُ فَإِنْ </span> 
 for you do not see Him but He certainly sees you.
```

Comment: What is  unclear? I want to add the code span every Arabic sentence, not per letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you `preg_replace("#([$arabic].+?(?=[a-z]))#us", '<span>$1</span>', $kata)`

I tried to use [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) but couldn't match Arabic diacritics properly.

The Code :

```
<?php

$arabic = "|ٮ|ٯ|ا|ب|ت|ث|ج|ح|خ|د|ذ|ر|ز|س|ش|ص|ض|ط|ظ|ع|غ|ف|ق|ك|ل|م|ن|ه|و|ي|ء|آ|ٱ|أ|إ|ة|ؤ|ئ|ى|ـ|،|؛|؟|٪|٫|٬|٩|٨|٧|٦|٥|٤|٣|٢|١|٠|ٍ|ِ|ْ|ّ|ٌ|ُ|ً|َ";

$kata = "
Excellence is to worship Allah as if you see Him
أَنْ تَعْبُدَ اللَّهَ كَأَنَّكَ تَرَاهُ فَإِنْ
فَإِنْ لَمْ تَكُنْ تَرَاهُ فَإِنَّهُ يَرَاكَ
for you do not see Him but He certainly sees you.

Excellence is أَنْ تَعْبُدَ to worship Allah فَإِنْ as if you see Him
";

// Check if Arabic characters in the string 
/* if(mb_ereg(".*\p{Arabic}.*", $kata)) { */
if(mb_ereg(".*[$arabic].*", $kata)) {
    /* echo preg_replace("#(\p{Arabic}.+?(?=[a-z]))#us", '<span>$1</span>', $kata); */
    echo preg_replace("#([$arabic].+?(?=[a-z]))#us", '<span>$1</span>', $kata);

}
else
{
    echo "Text doesnt have arabic characters.";
}

?>
```

Output :

```
Excellence is to worship Allah as if you see Him
<span>أَنْ تَعْبُدَ اللَّهَ كَأَنَّكَ تَرَاهُ فَإِنْ
فَإِنْ لَمْ تَكُنْ تَرَاهُ فَإِنَّهُ يَرَاكَ
</span>for you do not see Him but He certainly sees you.

Excellence is <span>أَنْ تَعْبُدَ </span>to worship Allah <span>فَإِنْ </span>as if you see Him
```

Comment: What if without enter? So the sentence is incorporated. like `Excellence is أَنْ تَعْبُدَ to worship Allah فَإِنْ as if you see Him`

Comment: Ok i'll waiting

Comment: So can u answer sir?

Comment: I've updated the answer 2 days ago. Tell me if something go wrong.

Comment: Last sorry,`([$arabic].+?(?=[a-z-A-Z-1-9]))` 
How to make a-z-A-Z-1-9 and all symbol exeption arabic? 
Because if there are numbers or uppercase after Arabic. Then, will be get `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

- Find out how arabic letters are encoded. Eg. [here](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%EF%BA%95%EF%BA%8F%D8%A2-arabic-alphabet/)
  As you can see, it starts at U+0600
- Parse `$kata` until you encounter such a character
- Insert `<span>`
- Continue parsing until the first non-arabic character
- Insert `</span>`
- Keep doing this until the end of the string.